# Can the enrichment of Uranium be done via manipulating the boiling/melting point difference between differing isotopes of the same element?

Tags: phase, isotope, distillation, nuclear, nuclear-chemistry

I have a Physics question for which I could not find the answer on the Internet, so I would like to see if y'all know the answer to it.

I have found that heavy water will have a different boiling point compared to light water, and this trend is present between various isotopes of an element. Based on this research, I have hypothesized that Uranium can be enriched using the procedure below.

1. Make UF6 (s)
2. Sublime it in a glass tube
3. Lower temperature with such precision, that one isotope of Uranium still remains in the gaseous form while another isotope has turned back into a solid.
4. Separate the gas and solid without disrupting the fragile temperature balance.

Although this link is for Germanium isotopes, it states that there is a 0.15 Celcius change of melting points between isotopes. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0921452618300863

So, here are my questions.

Would this apply similarly to Uranium, and how would the use of UF6 affect this boiling point difference?

How exactly does the boiling/melting point change between differing isotopes? And is there a particular formula for finding the melting point for a particular isotope? (I assume it would take in the number of neutrons and some other info)

In addition, is it possible to adjust the temperature of the entire system with decimal grade precision?

Furthermore, would the above setup work at all?

Also, if UF6 is too sensitive, would melting Uranium metal in a kiln with decimal precision temperature adjustability work?

Finally, is there a good, reliable source for melting point differences between isotopes?

I would like to first say that this is all purely theoretical and that I will take no action upon the information obtained; it is all merely a thought experiment to enhance my understanding of Chemistry and Physics. I mean, it's not like I'm gonna make a nuclear bomb; I'm just a normal HS student in the US. If you still think that this information might be dangerous out here, please PM me so we might work something out, like meeting via Zoom/Skype/Phone or something; I am very flexible about that.

I hope y'all have a great day.

Comment: Note that there is a separation method that uses an IR laser to do the separation, but obviously, the details are classified.

Comment: Since your question is basically about [distillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation), you might get more practical advice from [chemistry.se] rather than here at [physics.se]. We can migrate the question for you if you'd prefer to have it only in one place. If you end up posting your question on both sites, it's polite to link each post to its partner and to explain why you might hope for different advice from the different audiences.

Comment: @rob Yes, that would be wonderful, thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidWhite While that is true, enrichment via lasers(AVLIS, or SILEX for uranium) requires extreme precision. That is why I was seeking an alternative method, and it seemed like boiling/melting point differences seemed slightly more manageable than the 0.01nm difference between the excitement energy differences between U-235 and U-238. Thank you for your contribution, and I hope you have a nice day! I think you will also find this link entertaining.

Comment: @DavidWhite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_vapor_laser_isotope_separation

Comment: During WWII, there was used [gaseous diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaseous_diffusion) seperation technique for UF6, with the diffused part of the gas flow enriched by 235UF6.

Comment: @Poutnik This is a very good point. However, I am very curious if this mass difference(and consequently, phase change temperature difference) can be manipulated not just over a series of diffusion filters, but also via careful manipulation of the system's temperature within one or two glass tubes. If this were possible, it would have the effect of making isotope enrichment much more accessible. Thank you very much, and have a great day!

Comment: It is possible, but the separation would be less effective, that is why it was not used. It would not be question of careful temperature manipulation, but of very many repeated evaporation and condensation steps. The gaseous phase would be just very slightly enriched by 235UF6.

Comment: @Poutnik So would the process be as follows?

Comment: @Poutnik 1. Create UF6 and sublime in glass tube.    2. Oscillate the temperature rapidly between a very small interval somewhere around 2 degrees Celsius between the phase changing temperature of UF6.     3. Create some sort of process using a microprocessor that will let out a much higher percentage of solid U-238 than solid U-235, by letting out initial solid UF6 while trapping later solid UF6.     4. Repeat until needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course isotopes may be separated by distillation, but it's useful, AFAIR, only for hydrogen isotopes.
For uranium, gas centrifuge is proven much cheaper, to some orders of magnitude: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Газовая_центрифуга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)
(translate this page, it contains more information than English Wikipedia article).

The essence of this technology is known for decades, and included in basic chemistry textbooks. Only engineering/technological know-hows are sort of classified.
But in the politics, mass media, and perhaps on stackexchange, the whole topic is still considered taboo and is surrounded by fear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122694/discussion-on-answer-by-sa7-can-the-enrichment-of-uranium-be-done-via-manipulati).